Как удалить/скрыть Replay клавиатуру в aiogram
Проблема в том что мне нужно чтобы пропадала Replay клавиатура, и появлялась Inline клавиатура
Вот код которые есть сейчас
router.callback_query(F.data == 'text')
async def start(Call : CallbackQuery):
  await call.message.answer('text', replay_markup=apt)

В это же время мне надо удалить клавиатуру из прошлого хендлера

А что с вашими предыдущими вопросами на которые дали ответ?

А почему вас это заинтересовало

Дело в том, что вы не приняли ни одного ответа на свои вопросы, а так же не дополнили ни один свой вопрос самоответом.. Складывается впечатление, что вам совершенно не интересна судьба ваших вопросов‍♀️

Чтобы скрыть клавиатуру в aiogram боте, вы можете использовать параметр reply_markup с объектом ReplyKeyboardRemove
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardRemove

router.callback_query(F.data == 'text')
async def start(Call : CallbackQuery):
  await call.message.answer('text', reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())

